# remove all elements from a list that contains a string sequence from another list python

Tags: python

```
remove = ['files/2013/','files/2014/']
list = ['/5/files/2013', '/20/files/2014', '/31/files/2009', '/6/files/2008']
```

The final list should only contain

```
finallist = ['/31/files/2009', '/6/files/2008']
```

I tried the below code, but could not get it. Can anyone tell how and also explain the easiest way to do this?

```
remove = ['files/2013/','files/2014/']
list = ['/5/files/2013', '/20/files/2014', '/31/files/2009', '/6/files/2008']
finallist = []
 for a in list:
        for b in remove:
            if not b in a:
                finallist.append(a)
```

Comment: use the `any` function

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it masks the built-in type.

Comment: @NiklasB.: actually, `str.endswith()` is better here.

Comment: @Martijn cool, didn't know it works with lists as its argument. That somewhat goes against the python spirit of "there's exactly one obvious way" :P

Comment: @NiklasB.: it accepts a *tuple*; there is one obvious way to test for one or more ending strings; use a `str.endswith()`.

Comment: @Martin the obvious thing imo is combining any with endswith. Building the functionaloty into the function might be more efficient though (however I think it does not use aho-corasick, so there's probably no big difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to only *keep* values. Make `remove` a tuple so you can use [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
remove = tuple('/' + r.rstrip('/') for r in remove)
finallist = [f for f in files if not f.endswith(remove)]
```

I used `files` instead of `list` as the list of filenames to process. I also added `/` characters to the start of your filenames to remove, to prevent matching partial names, and removed trailing slashes, since your input list of filenames don't end in slashes either.

Demo:

```
>>> remove = ('/files/2013','/files/2014')
>>> files = ['/5/files/2013', '/20/files/2014', '/31/files/2009', '/6/files/2008']
>>> [f for f in files if not f.endswith(remove)]
['/31/files/2009', '/6/files/2008']
```

If you need to test for *containment* rather than ending, you'll need to use `any()` for efficient matching:

```
[f for f in files if not any(r in f for r in remove)]
```

which tests each string in `remove` in turn to see if it is contained in a filename; if so `any() returns`True` as soon as one such test succeeds.

Comment: is there a python equivalent of java's string1.contains(s2) ? Because I cannot be sure the string always ends with 'files/<some year>/', there could be 'files/<some year>/<some more nested folders>'

Comment: [f for f in files if not any(r in f for r in remove)] Can you explain how this works? I am from Java background if that helps.

Comment: @Naren: `(r in f for r in remove)` is a generator expression; each time you iterate over it (retrieve the next value), the `r in f` test is run; so for each string in `remove` we test if it is contained in the filename. `any()` does the work of iterating; as soon as such a test is `True`, `any()` stops looping and returns `True`. Otherwise it'll return `False`. So, it means that we only include filenames for which there is not any `r` in `remove` contained in the filename.